Identification of 3-pin auto module component 24 ETD43 with 'E' in 'E' logo
I can’t find anything about the following component. Can someone help with this?

I have done reverse image searches, looked through logo databases. Nothing.

The part number is also elusive to me and the net so far, although it appears to be a
straightforward one.

The complete assembly also has a part number. The only references to it are people
looking for the same.



The assembly is called an igniter. It controls the power to the high voltage ignition
coil in my car. It is located within the distributor.
It is controlled by rotating magnets that induce voltage into a coil that is connected
to this assembly. This part works.
It is a 12VDC system
Looks like these were manufactured from the 1980’s onward. This one most likely 1990's.

I am looking to replace the switching “transistor” (not sure, a Mosfet maybe).
Thank you.





What are the dimensions of the package? What car is this from? What's the part number of the assembly?

The dimensions of the package are: Width 10.00mm, Height 8.35mm.
I have not measured the thickness as there is a thick transparent conformal coating in the way.
The part is from a Suzuki Samurai.
I have added the Assy Number as a photo.

The manufacturer is Fuji Electric (富士电机). It's their old logo, the change is documented here for some of their parts.

The closest package I could find is T-Pack(L), here is a drawing from the 2SK3600-01L datasheet.

I can't find anything further about the part in question. ETD43 yields no results on their homepage or in their catalogs. I can't even find a picture of a part with a similar marking layout. I think your best bet is probably to contact Fuji Electric directly.

Thank You so much for your reply and effort! It helps me very much. You have certainly topped my work & also any AI instances I used. I suspect the component is a customised one made for NipponDenso. I will be contacting FE and see what comes about that.
